# JMeter and Content Disposition

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to emulate `POST` for stress testing with `JMeter`.

The "standard" `POST` (done by browser or `curl`) looks like:

```
POST /foo/boo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: localhost:4000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 8376
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------9dec6d453f478def

--------------------------9dec6d453f478def
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="plan.jmx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
....
```

However the request after `jmeter` lacks the `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` section:

```
POST /feedback/1.0/attack/ HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8331
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=qO2U87_27QtEGliQMv6ZGjIe6PnfEh1TX-RHAhJ
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)

--qO2U87_27QtEGliQMv6ZGjIe6PnfEh1TX-RHAhJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"
....
```

I looked at the XML and `jmeter` config looks like:

```
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
        <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
          <elementProp name="/Users/alexey/Work/all-attacks.zip" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
            <stringProp name="File.path">plan.jmx</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="File.paramname">filedata</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="File.mimetype"></stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
```

What is the way of specifying the `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` when using `jmeter`?

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as:

1. Check `Use multipart/form-data for POST`
2. Provide full path to file and `filedata` as "Parameter Name"

   - HTTP Request

     [image: Multipart Post]
   - View Results Tree listener output

     [image: View Results Tree]

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for comprehensive information on how to simulate file operations in your JMeter test.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any header into your request then you can add by passing those values into Http Header Manager (it'll be a child element for Http request)

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="plan.jmx"

Here Pass `Content-Disposition` in Name filed of header manger and rest in value field (no need to pass `:` ). It'll add this header in your request.

Also, are you getting proper response while executing this request from Jmeter? If not, try to change the implementation to Java of Http Request

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using `jmeter` installed by `apt-get` on a `ubuntu LTE`. That version was very old and presumably buggy.

The latest version downloaded from the `jmeter` web site doesn't have this issue and is reporting `filename` correctly.